# Add a column in pandas based on sum of the subgroup values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a simplified version of my dataframe (the number of persons in my dataframe is way more than 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person':['John','David','Mary','John','David','Mary'],
               'Sales':[10,15,20,11,12,18],
               })
```

```
  Person  Sales
0   John     10
1  David     15
2   Mary     20
3   John     11
4  David     12
5   Mary     18
```

I would like to add a column "Total" to this data frame, which is the sum of total sales per person

```
  Person  Sales  Total
0   John     10     21
1  David     15     27
2   Mary     20     38
3   John     11     21
4  David     12     27
5   Mary     18     38
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

I have tried

```
df.groupby('Person').sum()
```

but the shape of the output is not congruent with the shape of `df`.

```
        Sales
Person       
David      27
John       21
Mary       38
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the `transform` method which can apply a function on each group:

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('Person')['Sales'].transform(sum)
```

It gives as expected:

```
  Person  Sales  Total
0   John     10     21
1  David     15     27
2   Mary     20     38
3   John     11     21
4  David     12     27
5   Mary     18     38
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using the pandas groupby and sum functions.

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('Person')['Sales'].sum()
```

This will add a column to the dataframe with the total sales per person.

Comment: I tried that and indeed I got a new column "Total", but all the values in Total are NaN's. I checked the values of Sales and they are int64.

Answer (score 0):

your 'Persons' column in the dataframe contains repeated values
it is not possible to apply a new column to this via groupby

I would suggest making a new dataframe based on sales sum
The below code will help you with that

```
newDf = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Person')['Sales'].sum()).reset_index()
```

This will create a new dataframe with 'Person' and 'sales' as columns.